# Meteor SmartCollection giving inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, smartcollection

On the browser JS console, `News.insert({name: 'Test'})` caused `{{count}}` to increase from `0` to `1`.

In mongo console `mrt mongo`, `db.news.find().count()` returns `1`. However after adding a record via the mongo console `db.news.insert({name: 'TestAgain'})`, `{{count}}` remains at `1` while in mongo, there are `2` records now.

**Question:** What is causing minimongo and the mongodb console to give inconsistent results?

If I replace `Meteor.SmartCollection` with `Meteor.Collection` and reload the page, `{{count}` is now `2`. But if I were to change it back to `Meteor.SmartCollection`, `{{count}}` goes back to `1`!!

**collections/news.js**

```
News = new Meteor.SmartCollection('news');
```

**client/views/main.html**

```
<template name="news">
    {{ count }}
</template>
```

**client/views/main.js**

```
Template.news.count = function() {
    return News.find().count();
}
```

*Using Meteor v6.6.3 with SmartCollection v0.3.2.2*

---

### Update

By Cuberto's suggestion, I have enabled Oplog on my Mongodb server.

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://192.168.1.111:27017/myDb
export OPLOG_URL=mongodb://192.168.1.111:27017/local
mrt
```

`mongod` runs with `--replSet meteor` and mongodb was configured with

```
var config = {_id: "meteor", members: [{_id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"}]}
rs.initiate(config)
```

The prompt in `mongo` also becomes `meteor:PRIMARY>` and `db.local.` does contain the collection  `oplog.rs`.

Starting meteor, we see in the console `SmartCollection charged with MongoDB Oplog`.

**Problem:** However, nothing is retrieved when we try to do `News.find()` in the browser JS console. Doing the same query in `mongo` client returns the correct result. Switching from `Meteor.SmartCollection` back to `Meteor.Collection` allows the site to work again.

How can we troubleshoot the problem with SmartCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you configure your MongoDB to use oplog and set the environment variables, as explained here:

http://meteorhacks.com/lets-scale-meteor.html

Since smart collections removes the periodic database poll, you need to use an oplog-enabled mongodb instance to make it recognize DB changes from outside meteor.